# How to create button direct to url that query result from mysql

Tags: php, button

I have succeeded displaying data from query from mysql. But there is a url that connected to files that has been stored in mysql database. But I need to changes this url that text based to a button. Here is my script:

```
<td align="center"><a href='<?php echo $res['url_new_edition'] ?>'>New Edition</a></td>
```

Now I want to changes the 'New Edition' texts of course as a link/url into a button. I was already tried to add 'class=button', type='button' ect but none of works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='http://google.com'; return false;">
```

in your case

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $res['url_new_edition'] ?>'; return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a form instead of a href if you want a button. A clear solution that even comes along without JavaScript would look like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $res['url_new_edition']; ?>" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="New Edition" />
</form>
```